# Equivalent ideas of absolute continuity of measures

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Wikipedia says that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu$, if $\nu(A)=0 \Rightarrow \mu(A)=0$.

Okay, then I found another notion of absolute continuous measures: Let $||f||_1=1$ and $\mu(A):= \int_A |f| d \nu$, then we also have absolute continuity in the sense that if $\nu(A)  < \delta \Rightarrow \mu(A) < \varepsilon$. My question is: How are these definitions related to each other? It is clear that the second notion implies the first one, but is the converse also true? Where does this $\varepsilon$, $\delta$ comes into play?

Edit: Afais is the converse implication the result of a special case of the Radon-Nikodym theorem and a few lines of calculation that the $\varepsilon, \delta$ stuff actually holds, right?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first property, $\nu(A)=0\implies \mu(A)=0$, is the fundamental definition. The $\epsilon$-$\delta$ property is equivalent to it when $\mu$ is finite, but not in general. For example, the measure $\mu(E) = \int_E |x| \,dx$ on real line is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure. But we can find arbitrarily short intervals $I$ with $\mu(I)\ge 1$.

To prove the equivalence of two properties for a finite measure $\mu$, you don't need the Radon-Nikodym theorem. Suppose that the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ condition fails. Then there exists $\epsilon$ such that for all $n=1,2,3\dots$ there is a measurable set $E_n$ with $\nu(E_n)<2^{-n}$ and $\mu(E_n)\ge \epsilon$. Let $F_k = \bigcup_{n=k}^\infty  E_n$ and $F = \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty  F_k$. 
Since $\nu(F_k) <2^{1-k}$, we have $\nu(F)=0$. On the other hand, $\mu(F_k)\ge \epsilon$ for every $k$, which (because $\mu$ is finite) implies $\mu(F)\ge \epsilon$.

The proof is taken from Folland's ''Real Analysis'', which is generally considered a better way to learn measure theory than reading Wikipedia<sup>[*citation needed*]</sup>.

Comment: I solved the same problem but mine had $\mu$ as a signed measure...and I couldn't prove it like that. Do you have any idea on how to do it? :-)

Comment: I can't follow this step: "On the other hand, μ(Fk)≥ϵ for every k, which (because μ is finite) implies μ(F)≥ϵ"

Comment: Since $F = \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty F_k$, and these $F_k$ are decreasing, continuity from above says that $\mu(F) = \lim_{k\to\infty}\mu(F_k)$, but each $\mu(F_k) \geq \varepsilon$, so their limit has to be as well. The finite part comes into play because continuity from above ONLY holds if $\mu(F_1) < \infty$, which we cannot guarantee here unless we are explicitly told that the measure is finite.

Comment: @cupitor Based on the Folland proof, I assume the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ characterization is more concretely expressed as:  $$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta >0 : \forall \text{ measurable sets } A,  \\ \nu(A) < \delta \implies |\mu(A)| < \epsilon$$ ? More specifically, that the "$\forall \text{ measurable sets } A$" goes at the end of the chain of quantifiers and not the beginning?

Comment: @Cupitor Also, what is an example of an arbitrarily short interval with $\mu(I) \geq 1$?

Answer (score 5):

The easy way is just to note the following:

if $\nu(A)=0$ and $\mu <<\nu $, then setting $\epsilon =1/n$, we can find a $\delta_n>0$ s.t.$\ \nu(A)<\delta_n\Rightarrow \mu(A)<1/n$.

But this condition is vacuously satisfied for all $\delta_n$, because $\nu(A)=0$ so $\mu(A)<1/n$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$ and this implies that $\mu(A)=0$.