# Absolute continuity for positive measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $\nu$ and $\mu$ are positive measures on $(X,M)$, such that $\nu\ll \mu$, and $\nu$ is finite. Show that for every $\epsilon  > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $E\in M$ with $\mu(E) < \delta$, we have $\nu(E) < \epsilon$

We cannot trivialize this problem and use the Radon-Nikodym Theorem

Attempted proof: Proof by contradiction. Suppose we have $\epsilon  > 0$ such that for some $\delta > 0$ there exists a set $E$ with $\mu(E) < \delta$ and $\nu(E)\geq \epsilon$. Set $\delta = 2^{-j}$ and suppose we have a sequence $\{E_j\}_{1}^{\infty}$ in $M$. Let $$F_k = \bigcup_{1}^{\infty}E_j$$

I am not really sure where to go from here or if this is the correct approach, any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780824/equivalent-ideas-of-absolute-continuity-of-measures

Comment: You don't really need Borel-Cantelli lemma to prove this result. Please see my answer in: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1856721/real-analysis-folland-theorem-3-5-absoulute-continuity/1857185#1857185

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by contradiction, but your assumption should be that, there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that, for all $\delta>0$, there exists $E_{\delta}$ with $\nu(E_{\delta})\geq\varepsilon$, and $\mu(E_{\delta})<\delta$.

Then, for all $n\in\mathbb N$, there exists $E_n$ such that $\nu(E_n)\geq\varepsilon$ and $\mu(E_n)<\frac{1}{n^2}$. Since $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\mu(E_n)<\infty$, the Borel-Cantelli lemma shows that $$\mu\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty}E_n\right)=0.$$ Absolute continuity now shows that $\displaystyle\nu\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty}E_n\right)=0$. But, $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}E_n=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigcup_{m\geq n}E_m,$$ and also, for all $n\in\mathbb N$, $$\nu\left(\bigcup_{m\geq n}E_m\right)\geq\nu(E_n)\geq\varepsilon,$$ hence $$\nu\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty}E_n\right)\geq\varepsilon,$$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Question, would you agree that the way you used Borel-Cantelli lemma did not trivialize the problem?