# Real Analysis, Folland Theorem 3.5, absoulute continuity

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Background Information:**

Suppose that $\nu$ is a signed measure and $\mu$ is a positive measure on $(X,M)$. We say that $\nu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\mu$ and write $$\nu \ll \mu$$
if $\nu(E) = 0$ for every $E\in M$ for which $\mu(E) = 0$.

Theorem 3.5 - Let $\nu$ be a finite **signed** measure and $\mu$ a positive measure on $(X,M)$. Then $\nu\ll\mu$ **if and only** if every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $\lvert\nu(E)\rvert < \epsilon$ whenever $\mu(E) < \delta$.

Attempted proof: Let $\nu$ be a finite signed measure and $\mu$ a positive measure on $(X,M)$ and $\nu\ll\mu$. Then for any measurable set $E$ $$\nu(E) = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad \mu(E) = 0.$$

I don't really understand Folland's proof for this theorem, and I want to try to do this on my own but I am stuck. Any suggestions or comments is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1675111/absolute-continuity-for-positive-measures/1675122#1675122 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780824/equivalent-ideas-of-absolute-continuity-of-measures

Comment: This question does not seem to be a duplicate.  It is about **signed** measure and "**if and only if**" condition, which makes it distinct from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1675111/absolute-continuity-for-positive-measures/1675122#1675122

Also this question doe not assume $\nu$ is defined by density, which makes it distinct from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780824/equivalent-ideas-of-absolute-continuity-of-measures

Also, this question is specifically about Folland's proof of the theorem 3.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Wolfy , Folland's proof, in this case, follows what is possibly the short or more natural approach. However, as always Folland's proof is very terse.

Here are the proof in details.

> Theorem 3.5 - Let $\nu$ be a finite **signed** measure and $\mu$ a positive measure on $(X,M)$. Then $\nu\ll\mu$ **if and only if** every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|\nu(E)| < \epsilon$ whenever $\mu(E) < \delta$.

**Proof**:

**($\Leftarrow$)**

Suppose for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|\nu(E)| < \epsilon$ whenever $\mu(E) < \delta$.

It means: for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta_\epsilon > 0$ such that, for every measurable set $E$, if $\mu(E) < \delta_\epsilon$ then  $|\nu(E)| < \epsilon$.

Now,given any $E$ a measurable set such that $\mu(E)=0$. Then, for every   $\epsilon > 0$,  $\mu(E)=0< \delta_\epsilon$, and so $|\nu(E)| < \epsilon$.

Since, for every   $\epsilon > 0$,  $|\nu(E)| < \epsilon$, we have $|\nu(E)| =0$, that is, $\nu(E) =0$.

**Remark**: note that at this part (above) we don't need $\nu$ to be finite.

**($\Rightarrow$)**

Suppose $\nu$ be a finite signed measure and $\nu\ll\mu$. It is easy to see that  $|\nu|$ be a finite (positive) measure and $|\nu| \ll\mu$.

Now, let us prove that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|\nu|(E) < \epsilon$ whenever $\mu(E) < \delta$.

Suppose there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that for any $\delta > 0$ , there is a $E$ measurable set such that $\mu(E) < \delta$ and $|\nu|(E) \geq \epsilon$.

In particular, for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there is a $E_n$ measurable set such that $\mu(E_n) < \frac{1}{2^n}$ and $|\nu|(E_n) \geq \epsilon$.

Let $F=\bigcap_k\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty E_n$. Then, we have for all $k$,
$$0\leq \mu(F)\leq \mu \left(\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty E_n \right)<\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$$
So we have $\mu(F)=0$. So we have $|\nu|(F)=0$.

But $\left \{\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty E_n \right \}_k$ is a monotone non-increasing sequence of measurable sets and $|\nu|$ is finite. So we have

$$0=|\nu|(F)= |\nu|\left(\bigcap_k\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty E_n \right)=\lim_{k \to \infty} |\nu|\left(\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty E_n \right)$$

But for all $k$,
$$|\nu|\left(\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty E_n \right)\geq |\nu|(E_n)\geq \epsilon>0$$
Contradiction.

So we have proved that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|\nu|(E) < \epsilon$ whenever $\mu(E) < \delta$.

To conclude the proof, it is enough to remark that for every $E$ measurable set we have $|\nu(E)|\leq |\nu|(E)$. So we have that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|\nu(E)| < \epsilon$ whenever $\mu(E) < \delta$.