# Relation between the concept of Contiguity and Absolutely Continuous Measures

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory, self-learning

I have been digging a little bit more on Mathematical Statistics on my own and came across the concept of Contiguity between two sequences of probability measures, all defined on the same measureable spaces:

> Given a sequence of measureable spaces $(\Omega_n, \mathcal{F}_n)$ 
>    equipped with probability measures $P_n$ and $Q_n$, we say that the sequence of measures $\{Q_n\}$ is **contiguous** with respect to the sequence $\{P_n\}$ if, for any sequence of measureable sets $A_n$, it holds true that if 
>   $P_n(A_n) \rightarrow 0$ then $Q_n(A_n) \rightarrow 0$

Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contiguity_(probability_theory)

This definition resembles the definition of absolutely continuou probability measures with respect to another measure, but in a sequential setting. Are there known results linking the two concepts? I couldn't find any although I believe that absolute continuity for every index $n$ implies contiguity, although it's only a conjecture from a starter in this field.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}) = (\Omega_n, \mathcal{F}_n)$, $P=P_n$, and $Q=Q_n$ for all $n$, then contiguity is equivalent to absolute continuity.

See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780824/equivalent-ideas-of-absolute-continuity-of-measures).

Comment: Ok, nice result, thanks! Do you know any other implication in either direction?

Comment: @RaulGuarini The Wikipedia page states that your conjecture is false. I don't have a counterexample for you, but I think it's clear why the conjecture doesn't hold. You need something stronger than index-wise absolute continuity--some kind of uniform convergence--to derive contiguity.