# Absolute continuity of the Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

> Let $m$ be the usual Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^1$, and define $$\mu(E) = \int_E \frac{1}{1+x^2}dm(x).$$ Show that $m$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$.

This question concerns absolute continuity in a more general sense (same idea as the usual notion of absolute continuity of a function). To rephrase the question, we have to show that whenever $\mu (E)$ tends to zero, we also have that $m(E)$ tends to zero. So if $$\int_E \frac{1}{1+x^2}dm(x) \rightarrow 0,$$ then somehow $E$ shrinks to a set of measure zero. I don't know where to even begin, I thought of substitution or even a bound for the integrand but why are we integrating with respect to $dm(x)$?

Comment: $m(dx)=(1+x^2)\mu(dx)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. For instance, take $E_n := [n, n + 1]$, and observe that $\mu(E_n) \to 0$ but $m(E_n) = 1$. Absolute continuity is usually defined differently: we say a measure $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to a measure $\mu$ if $\mu(E) = 0 \implies \nu(E) = 0$. One can show that this definition and your definition are equivalent when $\nu$ is a *finite* measure (but $m$ is infinite, so these definitions are not equivalent in your case.) [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780824/equivalent-ideas-of-absolute-continuity-of-measures) has some more information if you're curious.

Comment: I can work your example out, by taking the bound $\frac{1}{1+x^2} \leq \frac{1}{x^2}$, then $$\int^{n+1}_n\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx \leq \int ^{n+1}_n \frac{1}{x^2}dx = -\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{n(n+1)}.$$ But do you think $dm(x)$ instead of $dx$ makes a difference here?

Comment: Usually, $dx$ always refers to the Lebesgue measure, so they should be the same unless you are using some other convention.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer provides the standard definition of what it means for $m$ to be absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$. For convenience, let $f(x) = \tfrac{1}{1+x^2}$. Suppose that $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mu(E) = 0$, then $$\int_E f(x) \, dm(x) = 0.$$ But $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. What does this imply?

Comment: If the measure of the region to be integrated over is already zero, then the integral should be zero no? Why does the fact that $f$ is positive matter?

Comment: The measure of $E$ with respect to $\mu$ is $0$. You are trying to show the same is true with respect to $m$. If the integral of a positive function is $0$ then what can we say about $m(E)$?

Comment: I would guess that it means $m(E)$ has to be zero too. But, how do you write it out rigorously? I would try the following to prove absolute continuity: $$\mu (E) = \int_E f(x)\, dm(x) \rightarrow 0$$ would imply that the integral of a positive function with respect to the usual Lebesgue measure (that's why it's written $dm(x)$) on $E$ tends to zero too. Therefore the only way this can happen is that the $m$-measure of $E$ tends to zero, which was exactly what we intended to show. Let me know how it sounds.